# iPhone - How to import native calendar events to my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, calendar

I am doing one simple application using iPhone calendar, where I need to import the iPhone native calendar events into my iPhone app. How can I do this. I have a piece of code but it doesn't  seems to be working. I have added some events into my iPhone native calendar. But when i retrieve it's not fetching anything. Here is the piece of code.

```
-(IBAction)importCalEvents:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *caleandarsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    caleandarsArray = [[eventStore calendars] retain]; 
    NSLog(@"Calendars from Array : %@", caleandarsArray);

for (EKCalendar *CalendarEK in caleandarsArray) 
 {
    NSLog(@"Calendar Title : %@", CalendarEK.title);    
 }        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can fetch all the calendar events like this.

import these 2 framworks (add if not exists into your project).

1 EventKit/EventKit.h

2) EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h

call this function on button click

```
-(void)EventList{

    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    NSDate *startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDate *endDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:3600 sinceDate:startDate];

    NSArray *calendars = [eventStore calendars];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate
                                                                 endDate:endDate calendars:calendars];
    NSArray *matchingEvents = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
    EKEvent *anEvent;

    NSLog(@"Total Events >> %d",[matchingEvents count]);

    for (int j=0; j < [ matchingEvents count]; j++) {

        anEvent = [matchingEvents objectAtIndex:j];

        NSLog(@"Title >>>%@",anEvent.title);
        NSLog(@"start date is %@ \n End Date is >>> %@",anEvent.startDate,anEvent.endDate);

    }   
}
```

And set the startDate and EndDate as per your Requirement.

so you can get all the detatils you want.

Best Luck..